# It is possible to set color columns with different values in vim?

Tags: vim

I know that I can `set textwidth` in vim so than I can automatically wrap my code (or text) when that value is reached.

I also know that I can color the first column after textwidth limit with `set colorcolumn=+1`.

Also I know that I can color more columns with `set colorcolumn=+1,+2,+3`.

Finally I know that I can set the color of the column with `hi colorcolumn ctermbg=10`.

Can I change the color of each columns with different values?

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is only one *highlight group* named `ColorColumn`. People have wished for different groups also for folding, but none of that is yet implemented.

You can emulate color columns (but only visible in those lines that have that many columns) via `:match`. For example:

```
:2match ErrorMsg /\%40v./
:3match WarningMsg /\%60v./
```